# How to write dataJsonArray values in angular js view

Tags: angular

I have a JSON array

```
$scope.dataObj={
  "dataElementCode": dataelementCode,
  "indicator": indicator,
  "categoryoptioncombo": categoryoptioncombo,
  "attributeoptioncombo": attributeoptioncombo,
  "value": value,
  "catId": catId,
  "orgGroup": orgGroup,
  "period": period,
  "storedBy": $scope.me,
  "lastUpdated": $scope.today
};
```

which gives the output like this :

```
0:
{
  dataElementCode: "NEW-1121120000000",
  indicator: "AaMkKZ4cy0D",
  categoryoptioncombo: "mYU1cpPLbA3",
  attributeoptioncombo: "X66r2y4EuwS",
  value: 14,
  …
}
1:
{
  dataElementCode: "NEW-1121120000000",
  indicator: "paKH35SUxZ8",
  categoryoptioncombo: "BpkvMcVXQgy",
  attributeoptioncombo: "X66r2y4EuwS",
  value: 0,
  …
}
```

I have to print these values in angular view. How it should be possible.

Comment: 1. It's not a JSON array, it's a JavaScript object. 2. Just use, for example `{{ dataObj.dataElementCode }}` in your view. This is the most basic thing you can possibly know about AngularJS. You should learn the framework by reading a book or the tutorials and the documentation before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat and show your required value like

In controller if array is something like:

```
$scope.r_array = [{dataElementCode: "NEW-1121120000000", indicator: "AaMkKZ4cy0D", categoryoptioncombo: "mYU1cpPLbA3", attributeoptioncombo: "X66r2y4EuwS", value: 14, …},{dataElementCode: "NEW-1121120000000", indicator: "paKH35SUxZ8", categoryoptioncombo: "BpkvMcVXQgy", attributeoptioncombo: "X66r2y4EuwS", value: 0, …}]
```

Then Required view will be something like

```
<div ng-repeat="data in r_array">
  <span>Indicator value: {{ data.indicator }}</span>
  <span>Attributeoptioncombo : {{ data.attributeoptioncombo}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="element in array">
      <p>{{element.item1}}</p>
      .
      .
      .          
     <p>{{element.itemN}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```